# Python excel drop down filter not working with openpyxl nor with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I was working in xlsxwriter and running into a problem with creating a dropdown list. The data validation didn't appear, even if I was sure I got the gist of the code. I started out with:

```
def english_fluency(pd_df, source):
"""data validation for english fluency"""
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(source, engine='xlsxwriter')
    pd_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Verification', index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Verification']
    worksheet.data_validation('E2', {'validate': 'list',
                                    'source': [' ', '1', '2',
                                               '3', '4']})
    workbook.save()
    workbook.close()
```

Because I felt like I kept running into a wall, I decided to switch over to openpyxl to try to accomplish the same thing more succinctly:

```
def english_fluency_dv(ws):
    """data validation for english fluency"""
    dv_ef = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"1,2,3,4"', allow_blank=True, showDropDown=True)
    ws.add_data_validation(dv_ef)
    return ws
```

I'm still unable to see the data validation drop down, maybe I'm missing something or placing it in the wrong area of the excel sheet?

Comment: The validation has not been applied to any particular range,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the right code with the wrong library. This code uses xlswriter to add validation to cell E2:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ValList.xlsx')  # open\create workbook
ws = workbook.add_worksheet('Verification')  # new sheet

# add validation list
ws.data_validation('E2', {'validate': 'list',
                          'source': [' ', '1', '2', '3', '4']})

ws.write("E2", '2')  # set cell value

workbook.close()  # save & close
```

Comment: Can you not set the data validation if it is a pandas df?